# Dragging a div element using "left" css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a css gradient generator and I need to make a slider with points to control the linear-gradient property. I would like to know how to move the points in such a way they are within the box.

I tried using the dragstart, drag, dragend Jquery functions but I can only move it to one side and it's not smooth. Please tell me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/suryakanigolla/jLbokcfm/2/)

```css
.gradientChanger {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.gradientPointer {
  width: 12px;
  height: 130%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: -8px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradientChanger">
  <div class="gradientPointer" style="left: 10%" id="pointer0"></div>
  <div class="gradientPointer" style="left: 30%" id="pointer1"></div>
</div>
```

Reference Image from https://cssgradient.io/

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show your attempt and ask about your code.

Comment: Apparently the site in question uses [interact.js](https://interactjs.io/) https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fcssgradient.io%2f - not sure I'd want to try this with jquery-ui tbh

Comment: @isherwood Okay I will, thanks for the link.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ohhh that's interesting. I'll try to make it in vanilla jquery if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i hope this will useful acording youre needs

```js
  $( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ]
    });
  });
```

```css
#slider-range .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 130%;
  outline: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: -8px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

#slider-range.ui-slider-horizontal {
  top: 1em;
  left: 5%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider-range" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And if you want to count the rang, i only can do this, get lucky  :)

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
      " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  } );
```

```css
#slider-range .ui-slider-handle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 130%;
  outline: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  top: -8px;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

#slider-range.ui-slider-horizontal {
  top: 1em;
  left: 5%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


#amount {
  left: 5%;
  visibility: visible;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  to/* p: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px; */
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<br/>
  <div id="slider-range">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Youre welcome, if you have something that i can help, just send me a message :)